# Why are there pauses between tests in TeamCity?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, configuration, teamcity

In some very old project, there are about 2K unit tests. Basically, the tests are divided into classes where possible.

I noticed in the log that when tests are run in TeamCity (2019.1.5), there are delays of about 10 seconds between them. Moreover, there are delays only when a new test class begins to run. There are no delays between tests of the same class.

What could be the problem? Do I have to refactor all the tests into some very large classes to eliminate the pauses? Maybe there are some special settings in TeamCity (I just started studying TeamCity)?

Comment: Do your test classes run some kind of setup?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think that yes, the tests themselves are also very old. Some of them are integration tests. If I understood correctly, the problem should be looked for in the tests themselves, and not in the TeamCity settings?

Comment: I don't have enough information to say that, but it's possible that your test classes are doing some kind of setup that causes a delay when the tests are started.

Comment: Perhaps you fork a new JVM for each test class, so the pause would be the start of a new JVM. Although 10s sounds long to start a new JVM, so there might be some additional setup code that runs each time a new JVM starts.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. But how can I check that a new JVM is forked for each test class?  And yes, I see a lot of inheritance in tests, some settings in `@BeforeClass` and `@Before`.